# Change leaf color

Tags: node-editor, color

I want to change the color of a leaf within Blender. But when working with brightness/contrast and hue/saturation/value I can't get the colors right no matter how I set the values. It never approaches the yellow golden color, it keeps staying a bit green.

Does the correct result need a different approach?

I attached a refference.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to change the color with the Hue/Saturation node, you could also use the RGB Curves, maybe share your file with the image packed inside.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the RGB Curves. I now attached the blendfile.

Comment: You didn't pack the images, but anyway, I tried with the image you display here and the Hue seems to work correctly, it crosses all the color spectrum, maybe you have a viewport refresh problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, it has them packed in now I believe. The viewport works fine, I just can't get the intense yellow color with the hue/saturation, but maybe that's my lack of skill. I tried the rgb curves, and this does give the intense yellow color, so thank you. However at the end I want to make a group node with all value sliders, this isn't possible I believe with the rgb curves?

Comment: please give a link to your image so that I try a setting

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1OGM1vv

Comment: If I'm right you should be able to download the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the *Hue/Saturation* node only. If you want yellow, as yellow is a bright brown color, you need to find the right *Hue* (0.35 seems good) and push the *Saturation* and *Value* pretty hight (2 and 10 here).

[image]

Comment: Ah like that, so I was just using the wrong hue to begin with. Thanks for sharing! I can now incorporate it in a group node with values :)

Answer (score 1):

With rgb curves. The colors are not right yet, but do have the intense color.
You can see the difference with the image in the question with hue/saturation.

[image]